# Bootstrap Offcanvas - do offcanvas css classes really exist?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I recently found out about twitter bootstrap and I have been diving deep into the most recent version, Bootstrap 3. On the website, there is an example for an "Off Canvas" template (here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/ ) which I have been modifying. But there are several things in the example that do not make sense to me.

In the "Off Canvas" template example, there are div elements that reference classes such as "row-offcanvas", "row-offcanvas-right", and "sidebar-offcanvas". I cannot find these in the bootstrap.css, and neither do I see these in the Chrome DevTools. I also do not see any effect when I remove these classes. Do these classes have any purpose? Or was it a mistake in the example to include those seemingly non-existent classes?

Comment: try to narrow the browser after removing those classes - you will see the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the page source closely you will find that in the header there is

`<!-- Custom styles for this template -->`

`<link href="offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">`

These classes are defined in there. And at least for me it does make a clearly visible difference if I remove this.

Answer (score 6):

As @mgttlinger mentioned the css is defined at `offcanvas.css` See http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/offcanvas.css

If want to a walk through of how it works see http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-11-05/creating-a-rwd-off-canvas-layout-with-bootstrap-3.aspx. It uses http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/ as the starting point and explains the css  used to create off canvas.

http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html#off-canvas is an excellent resource for more background on off canvas and most other responsive design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

i did experience the same dunno what i did wrong but js didnt seems to work i just remove all codes and link back all js and css not working. So i try other js on my other folders it work and copy them on my empty offcanvas page it works. Then put back all templates code and it works fine now i guess its my machine some components stop responding maybe just try restart.